# Should I let Jenkins merge branches, when using continuous delivery?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, jenkins-pipeline

I was wondering if letting Jenkins to merge a feature branch to master is a good practice or not? Should I merge the branch manually, and start a Jenkins pipeline/job when merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with having a feature automatically merged:

- Merge conflicts like Stony answered.
- Jenkins can't tell if the feature is done or not. Pushing to a remote doesn't mean the feature is finished, someone might want to review it first.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. What is if you have a merge conflict? You can't resolve them. So you should merge the branch on your computer and test the changes. Then push it and deploy it with Jenkins.

If you want to check your pushed changes before you can use a review system like Gerrit.